# How to delete Provisioned capacity units of AmazonGlaicer in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

While testing I clicked on Add 1 capacity unit an brought one under Amazon Glacier Provisioned capacity units.
Now I have tested the API;s and would want to delete it .I do not see an option to delete it.
Will I still be charged for this capacity unit

Answer (score 1):

A Glacier Provisioned Capacity Unit is an *optional* feature that you purchase, so that you have guaranteed capacity for restorations using expedited retrieval.  Once purchased, you have it available from now until 1 month from now, and it costs $100 regardless of whether you use it or not.  It wouldn't make sense if you could undo it yourself or if it was prorated, otherwise people would just turn it on, use it, and turn it off again, which is clearly not what they had in mind when billing it as a flat monthly rate regardless of usage.

You probably want to contact AWS account or billing support and explain the situation and see if they are willing to remove it.